# How to give user taking a quiz 2 chances to get the answer correct in python?

Tags: python, function

How to give user taking a quiz 2 chances to get the answer correct in python?

Comment: As a side note, you don't need—and probably don't want—to pass a bunch of separate strings like that to `print`; just do `print("\nQUESTION 3:\nWhich level of government is responsible for Tourism?")`. Or, alternatively, `print()`, then `print("QUESTION 3")`, then `print("Which level of government is responsible for Tourism?")`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is with a [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loop, with a `break` if they get it right, and maybe an `else` if they never got it right. For example:

```
for tries in range(2):
    print("\n", "QUESTION 3:", "\n", "Which level of government is responsible for Tourism?")
    print(" a) Municipal", "\n", "b) Fedral", "\n", "c) Provincial", "\n", "d) All", "\n", "e) Legislative")
    answer3 = input("Make your choice: ")
    if answer3 == "d" or answer3 == "D" :
        print("Correct!")
        break
    else:
        print("False!")
else:
    print("Out of chances!")
```

If you don't want to re-print the question each time, just move the `print` calls before the `for`.

The linked tutorial section (and the following few three sections) explain this all in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
def nTries(isCorrect, n = 2):
    answer = input("Make your choice: ")
    if isCorrect(answer):
        print("Correct")
    elif n == 1: 
        print("Out of tries, and incorrect")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        nTries(isCorrect, n - 1)
```

Set this up like this

```
print("\n", "QUESTION 3:", "\n", "Which level of government is responsible for Tourism?")
print(" a) Municipal", "\n", "b) Fedral", "\n", "c) Provincial", "\n", "d) All", "\n", "e) Legislative")

nTries(lambda d: d.lower() == 'd')
```

Comment: I don't think a user who even knows about loops is likely to understand how to use a higher-order function like this…

Comment: @abarnert yeah its still fun to do it this way. Its never to early to start looking at other ways to solve a problem.

Comment: This seems more universal `lambda d: d.lower() == 'd'`